# Play Framework: how to render "nested" list

Tags: groovy, playframework, rendering, template-engine

Issue with rendering of nested lists:

I have a class:

```
public MyRecord 
{
  String id;
  List<String > tags;
}
```

I have an object named 'records' which is of a type: List of 'MyRecord'.

I am trying to render itin JSON, using a template.

This is what I would **like** to do:

```
#{list records, as:'record'}
        {"c":[
            {"v":"${record.id}"},
#{list ${record.list}, as:'tag'}
    {"v":"${tag}"}
#{/list}           
        ]}
#{/list}
```

Unfortunately ${record.list} is not supported, and I failed to find a working solution.

Of course, I can add a method to MyRecord which will "render" the "tags" into the needed format, and use this method instead of the inner #{list}, but that's isn't in line with the templates approach. I am open to ideas to modify the data structure, if this will help to achieve the goal.

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${record.list} should be record.**tags**

```
#{list items:records, as:'record'}
 {"c":[{"v":"${record.id}"},
   #{list items:record.tags, as:'tag'}
       {"v":"${tag}"}
   #{/list}           
  ]}
#{/list}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually record.list is a copy/paste error. My real mistake was in using ${...} to get to the nested list.